# Select from multiple table, order the records with limits and union/join them together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P24GamesByCategoryDesktopEn]
    @Index int
AS
Begin
    SELECT GameName, IMG380X380, GameCode, '9' AS ProviderID  
    FROM BGames 
    WHERE GameType = 'slots' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, ImageUrl, GameID        , '12' AS ProviderID  
    FROM EGame 
    WHERE Type = 'slots' 
    ORDER BY GameName OFFSET @Index ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
END
```

I wan to select from two unrelated tables (that have no relationship between them) a number of records. Then I want to join the results of both table into one result set using the 'union' syntax.

However, the query doesnt work, because the order clause relates to the result set after the union has occured. That means that more records are returned from one of the tables.. but I need to return  an equal number of results from each select query. 
I want to use the order by clause after each select statement, but sql server wont allow such a syntax.

How can I join the tables and their results into one result set.

Note, I dont want to do a select subquery or create many temp tables. Thats because I am going to add a lot more select statements into that stored procedure..and I dont want it to be inefficient or too convulted.

Comment: Why not run two statements, one for each table?

Comment: I am not sure how it would work when I try to receive it with C#. Is it posssible to iterate over such results? And is it possible to assign such results to a model class in C# (for example, using linq ?

Comment: @danmann - So if you would like to return 4 rows (in the fetch statement), this means you want 4 rows from the first select and 4 from the second one? Or 2+2, whatever, my point is you would like for it to work like that?

Comment: Unfortunately that is how union works.

Comment: Yes. @MK_ . I also want the ordering to work for each statement to work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much just need to wrap up your different queries that you want to order by and "paginate" in CTE's like so:

```
DECLARE @Index int = 0, @NbrOfRows int = 4

; WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT GameName, IMG380X380, GameCode, '9' AS ProviderID  
    FROM BGames 
    WHERE GameType = 'slots'
    ORDER BY GameName
    OFFSET @Index ROWS FETCH NEXT @NbrOfRows ROWS ONLY
), CTE2 AS (
    SELECT Name, ImageUrl, GameID, '12' AS ProviderID  
    FROM EGame 
    WHERE Type = 'slots' 
    ORDER BY GameName
    OFFSET @Index ROWS FETCH NEXT @NbrOfRows ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT * FROM CTE1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE2
```

You just need to add naming to the columns so that they are as you wish them to be at the end of the union.

Comment: An interesting idea. Is it more efficient than using separate select statments?

Comment: It's not more efficient then using SELECT1 UNION ALL SELECT2 (it's pretty much on par with it), however it gives you the ability to do what you've wanted - do different ordering from each of your source tables and based on that ordering use OFFSET FETCH clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get around this with row_number().
This is two selects of the same table but it could be different tables.

```
SELECT [AuctionId]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[BiddingPrice]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,9 as [source] 
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [DateTime] asc) as rn
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Bid] 
union all
SELECT [AuctionId]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[BiddingPrice]
      ,[DateTime]
      ,12 as [source]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [DateTime] desc) as rn
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[Bid] 
ORDER BY rn, source OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Nice answer, but the same problem exists. It will return you 4 rows from the second row record on all the result set. I want to return 4 rows for each select statement instead of all of them combined.